# Prove the if $a\nmid x$ and $a\nmid y$ then $a\nmid xy$

Tags: number-theory

I need help proving that if $a\nmid x$ and $a\nmid y$ then $a\nmid xy$. I want to do this preferably without a counterexample. I already know that this is False, but I want to know how.

Comment: Huh? You're looking for a proof that the statement does not hold without actually giving a counterexample? Have you tried considering what the common theme in all counterexamples to the statement is (in particular, regarding factorizations)?

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh. Ok then what would be a counterexample?

Comment: $4, 2, 2 {}{}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers Would $x=2,y=3,a=6$ work?

Comment: That also works.

Comment: It is true if $a$ is prime however.

Comment: "I want to do this preferably without a counterexample." Huh? Why?

Comment: @nhcs do you have thoughts on the provided answers?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. $4\nmid 2,4\nmid 2,$ but $4|4$. If you want to disprove the statement, a counter example is all you need. How else would you disprove it?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I agree with this answer 100%.

Answer (score 1):

a=6, x=2, y=3

That's enough.

But I need more characters.